# Corona virus in Netzavim Vayeilech

Tags: parashat-nitzavim, vayelech

The Vilna Gaon [said](https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=114) that each Parsha in Devarim corresponds to 100 years between 5000-6000 years of creation, making our generation somewhere in Nitzavim-Vayeilech. Being that corona virus has had such a global impact, it should be included in the Parsha - which words allude to it?

Note: Though I have no idea whether one would look at the number of verses, words, or a completely other method to identify the year one is in, since there are 70 verses between the two parshiyos, and we are 80% into this period of 1940-2040 ([see](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=123993) Rabbi Glatstein's shiur for that particular series of years), the 80% mark of these 70 verses would be [Devarim 31:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.31.16?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=bi) entering 31:17:

> וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֶל־מֹשֶׁה הִנְּךָ שֹׁכֵב עִם־אֲבֹתֶיךָ וְקָם הָעָם
> הַזֶּה וְזָנָה אַחֲרֵי אֱלֹהֵי נֵכַר־הָאָרֶץ אֲשֶׁר הוּא בָא־שָׁמָּה
> בְּקִרְבּוֹ וַעֲזָבַנִי וְהֵפֵר אֶת־בְּרִיתִי אֲשֶׁר כָּרַתִּי אִתּוֹ׃ - The LORD said to Moses: You are soon to lie with your fathers. This people will thereupon go astray after the alien gods in their midst,
> in the land that they are about to enter; they will forsake Me and
> break My covenant that I made with them.
>
> וְחָרָה אַפִּי בוֹ בַיּוֹם־הַהוּא וַעֲזַבְתִּים וְהִסְתַּרְתִּי פָנַי
> מֵהֶם וְהָיָה לֶאֱכֹל וּמְצָאֻהוּ רָעוֹת רַבּוֹת וְצָרוֹת וְאָמַר
> בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא הֲלֹא עַל כִּי־אֵין אֱלֹהַי בְּקִרְבִּי מְצָאוּנִי
> הָרָעוֹת הָאֵלֶּה׃ - Then My anger will flare up against them, and I
> will abandon them and hide My countenance from them. They shall be
> ready prey; and many evils and troubles shall befall them. And they
> shall say on that day, “Surely it is because our God is not in our
> midst that these evils have befallen us.”

Comment: 29:14 is clearly referencing the blended model of half the people coming in person and the other half joining remotely.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112815/discussion-on-question-by-njm-corona-virus-in-netzavim-vayeilech).

Answer (score -1):

I think this year's passuk is

כִּי גוֹי אֹבַד עֵצוֹת הֵמָּה וְאֵין בָּהֶם תְּבוּנָה.

That seems to be a pretty apt description of the current world political situation, including the response to Covid-19.

I.e. the klalah is, "You will respond inappropriately to a difficult situation in which you find yourself."